# What is wrong with my popup window code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After the code I will link a JSFiddle that show's what the code is and what it is supposed to do.
I'm working on making a popup and having it so the background around it fades out when the pop up is visible. It works in the JSFiddle but not in the webpage. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="stylesheets/jquerystylesheet.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    display:none; 

    /* color with alpha transparency */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    /* stretch to screen edges */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;

    /* center it ? */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">Some popup text</div>
<p>Some content text (click anywhere to toggle overlay)</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$("body").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").toggle(); // show/hide the overlay
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle I obtained it from:

http://jsfiddle.net/eohvutps/

Here is my JSFiddle (the code doesn't work in that either so I must have done something wrong.):

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/f795dy3v/)

Comment: You probably haven't added jQuery to your site.E.g: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: yep it s missing jQuery just see here http://jsfiddle.net/f795dy3v/2/

Comment: Have you added javascript libraries, JQuery etc?

Comment: As @Ruddy says, you're missing jQuery in your fiddle/example code. For reference, if you have your browser developer tools open, you see error indicating something is amiss: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? It would be a beginners mistake.

Comment: @Mark I downvoted as it was essentially a copy/paste of some code, with no effort into researching why it's not working.  A quick comparison of the two jsfiddles linked clearly shows jquery being included on the one that works.  If you flick between two tabs with them both open, the differences are glaringly obvious.

Comment: I think @Mark is right that its very much a beginners mistake, but simply searching SO first would have provided the answer. Also the error is very obvious if you just look at the console; 3 whole mouse clicks away :P

Comment: It is my first time using jquery as well as looking at it. I did research before hand and I either found the answer and didn't recognize it/understand it. So I figured it would be more helpful and beneficial to receive help from people helping me personally. Thanks to those that helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included the Jquery library in your fiddle. Have you included in your webpage? If not, this will be your issue.

Comment: And this was down-voted why? This is very clearly what is wrong with the fiddle.

Comment: To be fair you didn't even put a real answer. Including the fix (the script tag) would be a lot better.

Comment: I like Mark's answer much better. At least the person that did the copy/paste has to research how to include jQuery in the code. We're here not just to help but to help improve as well and I can't see providing him more things to copy paste helping him.

Comment: @Ruddy, you don't need the script tag in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Mark Did you even read my comment? I was saying you could have told the OP how to include jQuery in there webpage. Just adds a little something to your answer, so its more than just a line of text.

Comment: @gothical I disagree, when I started learning jQuery etc there was a lot of copy and pasting. You then read over it and then next time you will have an idea how to fix the problem. Then one day it will just be something you know. And also this is the only answer here so by default it would be the answer you like most.

Comment: @Ruddy That's exactly what's wrong with the way people like you think. Just because jsfiddle has an answer area, you think its the only answer even though the comment field exists which are clearly answers as well. Regarding your first point. Copying and pasting doesn't really teach you jQuery, researching does. To quote the first guideline of stackoverflow.com to ask questions "Search, and research".

Comment: @gothical, but to Copy and Past one must have searched and researched.

Comment: @gothical Comments are... comments. People like me that feel no need to answer a question such as this (because you can find thousands of the answers around the site). Copy and pasting lets you take the code to an environment of your choosing, what you do with it there is up to you. Im not sure what your talking about with the first guideline of SO. I also fail to see whats wrong with the way "people like me" think.

Comment: "comments are .. comments". The first comment was yours and that was the answer to the OP's question. You not understanding the first guideline of stack overflow to ask questions would've been found if you searched but oh well here you go http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.